# address-size override with near calls in long mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Intel manual (Vol.2 paragraph 2.2.1.6) says:

> The use of the address-size prefix does not disable RIP-relative
>   addressing. The effect of the address-size prefix is to truncate and
>   zero-extend the computed effective address to 32 bits.

`CALL rel32` description says:

> Call near, relative, displacement relative to next instruction. 32-bit
>   displacement sign extended to 64-bits in 64-bit mode

Thus, `rel32` is immediate rather than address, as operand-size prefix overrides the default value.

But if use address-size override prefix with `near call` (or `jmp`), will it zero-extend effective address as described above or it won't have any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the type of RIP-relative addressing that a 67-prefix might target, a 67-prefix has no effect on call/jmp/jcc offsets (rather it is the 66-prefix that affects, for example, `call rel16` vs `call rel32`).

The type of RIP-relative addressing par 2.2.1.6 talks about is the sort of thing encoded by a ModRM byte that looks like 00***101, for example in something like

```
mov rax, [eip]
; or,
addr32 mov rax, [eip]
; or if your assembler doesn't let you write either of those,
db 67
mov rax, [rip]
```

this is one of the cases they meant, where rip-relative addressing is still active but truncated. If addressing reverted completely like how it is in 32bit mode, a ModRM like 00***101 would encode `[sword]` with no eip-involvement at all.